# How to extract only specific words from a string that contains delimiters in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, split

I have the following string in Google Sheets:

**222222*1 - preroll - MINE - Homepage - CTA - redirect**

and I want to extract only specific parts of this string.

For example, I would like to extract only these

- **222222*1**
- **preroll**
- **CTA**
- **redirect**

in order to create for example another string like this: **222222*1_preroll_CTA_redirect**

I have already tried the Regexextract and the Split function without success. I'd like to extract only specific elements that are delimited by the dash and then concatenate them in the way I need, and possibly all at once.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75224888/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of say 10 rows of sample data side-by-side your manually entered desired results.

Comment: Please add the regex you tried, when adding the regex tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexextract()` and `join()`, like this:

```
=join( "_", regexextract(A2, "^(.+?) - (.+?) - .+? - .+? - (.+?) - (.+?)$") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @doubleunary! I see that this formula extracts the elements sequentially, but I need to extract specific elements as shown in the example below:

[Table with the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czrr4.png)

Let me know if this is clear.